# Regular expression for multiline commentary in Matlab

Tags: java, regex, matlab, comments

I try to write a regexp that would match this pattern:

```
%{
...
...
%}
```

It should also match:

```
sth   %{
...
...
  %}
```

or

```
%{
something%}
%}again something
%}
```

but not:

```
%{something
...
%}
```

or

```
%{
...
%}something
```

or

```
%{
...
something%}
```

So it matches everything between a line with whatever character followed by %{ and a line with only %} (see multiline comment Matlab : https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comments.html)

I tried this :

```
     ^.*%\{\n(^((?!%\}).)*\n)*(\s)*%\}\n
```

It works well to find the block, but for example, it doesn't match:

```
%{
%}something
...
%}
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Try `^.*%\{\n(?:(?!%\{).*\n)*\s*%\}$`, see https://regex101.com/r/6AvzYN/1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't seem to work, see https://regex101.com/r/6AvzYN/3

Comment: i feel like it works even in the link you provided. Should the last example be match or not?

Comment: In the last example I provided, you can see the line leftpanel=treepanel is matched as well or it shouldn't. But if I remove the whitespaces at the beginning of the line, it matches correctly.

Comment: `^.*%\{(?:\n(?!.*%\{).*)*\n\s*%\}$`? See https://regex101.com/r/6AvzYN/4

Comment: Oh nice thank you ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^.*%\{(?:\n(?!.*%\{).*)*\n\s*%\}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6AvzYN/4). Use it with a multiline modifier.

If your regex engine is Java, you may use `\R` to match any line break and `\h` instead of `\s` to match any *horizontal* whitespace:

```
^.*%\{(?:\R(?!.*%\{).*)*\R\h*%\}$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6AvzYN/5).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `%\{` - a `%{` substring
- `(?:\n(?!.*%\{).*)*` - 0 or more sequences of

  - `\n(?!.*%\{)` - a newline not followed with `%{` anywhere on the current line
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\n` - a newline
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `%\}` - a `%}` substring
- `$` - end of line.